# Cheerio Incomplete Html

Tags: javascript, cheerio

i'm trying to **scrape** a website using cheerio

```
const rp = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


rp('https://www.fideyo.com/list',(error,response,html) =>
{
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    {
     const $ = cheerio.load(html); 
          
     console.log($.html());
    }    
});
```

but it returns an incomplete html body like

```
<body>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.fideyo.com/static/main.js?v=13"></script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KBGVCP3"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden">
    </iframe>
</noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

</body></html>
```

[when i load site from chrome there is content in app section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUHNY.png)

how can i reach content in app section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the content in app section may be created dynamically by JavaScript, and `cheerio` does nor run JavaScript, just parses the hardcoded HTML.

You need something like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/ :

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto('https://www.fideyo.com/list');

  await page.waitForSelector('div#app div#page-wrapper a');

  const html = await page.content();
  console.log(html);
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

The docs are here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md